# How not to display the language if the user has this language?

Tags: laravel, if-statement, foreach

I display all the `languages` in a view by using `foreach` but I don't want to display the language if the user has that language saved .

**As an example**

As options in the select, I have 3 languages (english, Korean, Japanese).

If the user has saved English as language in the table, it should'nt be displayed in the options.

This is the model for `language`.

```
protected $fillable = [
        'language'
    ];
public function userlanguage()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserLanguage::class);
    }
```

this is my model for the user

```
protected $fillable = [
        'user',
        'language_ID',
    ];
public function languages()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Languages::class, 'language_ID');
    }
```

This is the controller

```
public function index()
{
   $userlanguages = UserLanguage::with('user', 'languages', 'proficiency')->where('user_ID', Auth::user()->id)->get();
   $languages = Languages::all();

   return view('userlanguage',[
            'languages' => $languages,
            'userlanguages' => $userlanguages
   ]);
}
```

This is the view

```
<select name="language">
    @foreach( $languages as $language )
        <option value="{{ $language->id }}">{{ $language->language }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
                                                                                </select>
```

I don't know how to not display the user's saved language in the options.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide visually, you can add a class to option like

```
<option
    :class="{hidden: $language->id == $userLanguage->id}"
    value="{{ $language->id }}"
>{{ $language->language }}</option>

//in CSS
.hidden {display: none;}
```

If you want to exclude the language completely:

```php
<select name="language">
    @foreach( $languages->filter(fn ($l) => $l->id != $userLanguage->id) as $language )
        <option value="{{ $language->id }}">{{ $language->language }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the @if method on select option.

```
<select name="language">
      @foreach( $languages as $language )
         @if ($userlanguages != $language)
           <option value="{{ $language->id }}">{{ $language->language }}</option>
         @endif
      @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Looks to me `$userlanguages` would be an array, so just using an `if` won't suffice

Comment: Oh ya, sorry about that. Didn't notice the get() on the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding @if to the select option

```
  @foreach( $languages as $language )
     @if ($userlanguages != $language)
       <option value="{{ $language->id }}">{{ $language->language }}</option>
     @endif
  @endforeach
```

Comment: Looks to me `$userlanguages` would be an array, so just using an `if` won't suffice